# Wordpress enlarging images by 4/3

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

Not a Wordpress expert, but reasonably well versed in HTTP/HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc. Customer has a Wordpress site of not recent vintage, and I want to just get in, do the minimal required work, and get out. A page needs an image, so I upload it to the "Media Library". Push buttons and doodads to insert it into page, view the result and... the image looks blurry.

Some hours later, I understand there's a ton of Q&A about blurry images on Wordpress, but AFAICT they have nothing to do with my problem. When I view the image in a browser, it is reliably being scaled up by precisely 4/3 (1.33333...).

What drives me nuts is, I pick a browser, load the page, go into the console debugger, and it agrees both that the image is being rendered at 4/3, but also knows exactly what the correct original size is. Fine, but I should be able to see *why* it is rendering at 4/3. I cannot locate any relevant CSS parameter that is causing this. I have tinkered with enumerable combinations, including elaborations where I shove the img in a div and set the width of that div, etc. Every single time, the browser calmly scales the image up.  In Firefox's console debugger, the "box model" view displays the actual original size rather than the scaled-up blurry size.

I feel I have eliminated PHP and Wordpress by just using <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> or the browser debugger to look at the result. But apparently somebody has managed a trick I don't understand, so I'm not sure whether to view this as a Wordpress question, CSS question, or what. So I'm flinging this question out in case the magic scale factor of 4/3 rings a bell with someone who immediately knows what the problem is. Let me know if other info is required to locate the problem.

Comment: Do you have a URL we can look at? Smells like a CSS issue.

Comment: I agree. But I sense I must be about to learn a new CSS trick, because I sure can't see the problem. I'll make a special page just to show the problem: http://teamsurvivornw.org/test/

Comment: Hmm, what browser are you using? The dimensions look correct in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I have used Firefox and IE. If you ask either of them the dimensions of the displayed image by right-clicking on it, they will report the actual dimensions of the original bitmap. However, note that it is actually being rendered at 4/3 the size. Are you saying you're seeing it actually *rendered* at the correct size on your Apple machine?

Comment: I just checked it in IE11 on a virtual machine running Win10 and it was the correct size. It may sound daft, but are you sure you haven't accidentally enabled zooming in your browser? Also, how exactly are you measuring the rendered dimensions?

Comment: That's the most idiotic thing I've done this year. You're right, it is browser zoom. For my future reference, I also note: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/how-do-you-handle-clients-browser-zoom       Please make that an answer and I'll accept it -- and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked it in IE11 on a virtual machine running Win10 and it was the correct size. It may sound daft, but are you sure you haven't accidentally enabled zooming in your browser?

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the time you took on my stupid error.

Comment: No problem. I've made the same error myself, and had two clients make the same error, so you're not alone!

Answer (score 0):

This might sound simple-stupid, but sometimes, we all tend to miss something trivial:

While inserting the image/s into page, there is a column called **ATTACHMENT DETAILS** (extreme right). Down below on this column, there is a **Size** dropdown. Have you tried adjusting that? HTH.

Comment: Good guess, but alas the Size dropdown is set to "Full Size" and indeed displays the correct dimensions of the original bitmap.